# Destination amount in different currency than charged amount currency in stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Let's say I have a scenario, to create a charge in USD with destination amount in AUD
What I want is

```
  Stripe::Charge.create({
    source: 'tok_xxx',
    amount: 2000,
    description: "etc...",
    currency: 'USD',
    capture: false,
    destination: {
      account: seller_account_id,
      amount: 2000 - 400,
      currency: 'AUD'
    }
  }.merge(metadata: {...}))
```

[Example explained here..](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#example-scenarios)

Unfortunately, I don't find any helpful documentation. Other than this I'm open to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a currency to be used in the destination part of the Charge request, instead can you only supply the [destination account and amount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=ruby#create_charge-transfer_data). The amount here will match the currency you're making the Charge in.

To achieve what you want you could make the charge on your platform account, then use the [Transfers API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create?lang=ruby) to make the transfer in the different currency.